# Where can be Ejabberd.yml?

Tags: windows, ejabberd

I want to configure Ejabbered.yml I've checked different paths.

> 1> C:\Users\Abhishek\AppData\Roaming
>
> 2> C:\Program Files\ejabberd-17.04\bin\

I am not able to find anywhere.

Please help

Comment: Did I asked something dumb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not available on the ejabberd website

I found mine in: C:\ProgramData\ejabberd\conf